# Google's Cloud Speech API Speech Volume

Tags: cloud, speech, google-cloud-speech

I'm attempting to measure the volume of a user's voice with the Google Cloud Speech API.

Does Google's Cloud Speech API expose user's speech volume?

I've been exploring their documentation (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics), and it's not clear if it exists.

Comment: Google Cloud Speech API does not currently include speech volume in the response.

I assume you want to track the change in speech volume over time?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to depend volume measuring from Google Speech API.

You need to find some audio observer utility to pass your audio stream or file to detect volume